# SPOnline trouble mapping crawled and managed properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, crawled-property

I have created a list with site columns.
In search schema, columns appear in crawled properties but i can't map them to any managed properties. Even refinable properties.
[image: Picture : On clic on managed property, the only action is view property]
**Modify/Map property** action is not available.

Am I missing something, like a feature to activate ?

Environment : 
SharePoint Online. 
"SharePoint Server Standard Site features" and "SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features" are active.
I'm Site collection administrator. 
I can't access Sharepoint search administration.

Comment: If you created columns as site columns, managed properties would be created automatically for those site columns. No need to map them. You only need to map a column if you create it in the list directly because then SharePoint will only create a crawled property.

Comment: I can see those managed properties but they appear in grey. I'm not sure that I can use them in display template and in refiner.

Comment: You can do a quick try! Add a content search web part and edit the webpart and try to map it to some of your managed properties that are greyed out to see if they work. If they do, you can use them in your display template.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it don't work. I can't see them. That's why i would like to be able to map my crawled properties to refinable managed properties as I know I can use them as refiners and in display template.
The thing is that the Map property action is not available in the site collection schema. So i don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was cheated by my switch from SharePoint on premises to SharePoint Online.
I was not going to the right place.
[image: SITE search schema : read only]
url is like : tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=**site**

[image: SITE COLLECTION search schema : can be modified]
url is like : tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=**sitecol**